# No Room to twist and change Florescent Bulbs

Tags: light-fixture

I have a kitchen Florescent light fixture with two of four bulbs not working.  Unfortunately, the fixture frame and other bulbs are so close I am unable to get a good grip on the bulbs necessary to twist, remove and change bulbs.  Does anyone know a trick to enable me to change these two bulbs?

Comment: You'd have to tell (or show) us something about your fixture.

Comment: I've worked with close-spaced bulbs. The challenge was getting enough grip on the first one to remove it - then the others are much easier. I put on latex surgical gloves and got enough grip using the tips of all my fingers from both hands.  (I'm assuming this is your problem?)

Comment: It's rare that there isn't a grille or something that can be swung out of the way or removed. We have no idea from the information provided.

Comment: Can you post photos of the culprit fixture?

Answer (score 1):

Are you quite sure these tubes twist off?  Some of them go straight in.  Look closely; if you see two slots, don't twist them (much).